# Convert years to months; and years to days using python

Tags: python, datetime, python-datetime

Could someone help me to convert number of years to months and number of years to days using `input` method?
Output should be like this:

```
>>> MyFunction()
# Input
2

# Output
2 years = 24 months
2 years = 730.50 (rounded) days
```

Comment: Try multiplying the number of years by 365 to get the days and by 12 to get the months

Comment: Is that a homework? If not, the `datetime` module has all the conversions you need.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far, and what issues have you encountered? Are you following a tutorial or class? Have you tried reading up on how input and math work in Python?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can multiply the years with 12 to get months and multiply it with 365 to get days. If it is more than 4 years then also add years//4 to days as you get one extra day every leap year. You code:

```
years=int(input("Enter years= "))
print("Months: ",years*12)
print("Days: ",((years*365)+years//4))
```

Comment: This is correct, but  I'd recommend giving [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) a read. It's usually better to point students in the right direction than to give them complete code they can copy and paste.

Comment: Yeah I know, but what I personally think is, they are beginners. I always ensure that I try to explain my whole code so that by reading it, they can definitely learn how to think and approach the question which may help them in future. That's why I don't prefer telling them how to ask questions